# Histogram in gnuplot - bins not separated one from another

Tags: gnuplot

Sorry for my English,

I would like to make a histogram in gnuplot, where bins are not separated one from another by vertical lines, something like it is shown in the following figure:

[image: Histogram]

I usually use "plot [...] with boxes" command to make a histogram, but it leads to a histogram with such vertical lines, which make the histogram unclear for bigger number of bins in the plot.

My data consists of two values for every value of x.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you checked `help steps`?

Comment: @theozh Thank you, it is what I have looked for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My comment again as answer, according to the StackOverflow "rule": no answers in comments...

You are probably looking for:

```
plot ... with steps
```

Check `help steps`. You may also want to check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/56047577/7295599) about steps.

Comment: Or maybe he prefers `w histeps`