# Gnuplot: Plot stepwise discontinuities in a cumulative distriubtion

Tags: gnuplot

When I plot a cumulative distribution with gnuplot, it interpolates between datapoints; this is seen in the purple curve. How can I plot my data as a stepwise function like the black curve? Something similar to the [step method in matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/step_demo.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-step-demo-py).

[image]

### Source data

```
1,1,0
1,2,0
1,3,0
1,4,2
1,5,1
1,6,3
1,7,3
1,8,1
1,9,3
1,10,8
1,11,1
1,12,0
1,13,3
```

### Gnuplot source

```
set terminal pngcairo font ",14"
set output "cumulative.png"
#set terminal qt font ",14"
set title "Cumulative count" font ",16"
set xlabel "episode"
set ylabel "cumulative count"
set xtics 1
set key bottom right
set grid
unset border

set datafile separator comma
plot "season-01-count.csv" u 2:($3) smooth cumulative title "cumulative count"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you done a search or checked the manual at all? Check `help steps` or check here: http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_5.2/steps.html or the graph here: [How to plot same value until it change?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56034104/7295599)

**Code:**

```
### plot with steps
reset session

$Data <<EOD
1,1,0
1,2,0
1,3,0
1,4,2
1,5,1
1,6,3
1,7,3
1,8,1
1,9,3
1,10,8
1,11,1
1,12,0
1,13,3
EOD

set title "Cumulative count" font ",16"
set xlabel "episode"
set ylabel "cumulative count"
set xtics 1
set key bottom right
set grid
unset border

set datafile separator comma
plot $Data u 2:($3) smooth cumulative with steps lw 2 lc "red" ti "cumulative count"
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]