# Gnuplot: filling and fsteps

Tags: gnuplot

I have daily data (one point per day) which I plot with Gnuplot using `fillsteps`.  `fillsteps` fills the space between a line done with `steps` and zero.

However, what I would like is filling the space between a line done with `fsteps` and zero.

The easiest way that comes to mind is avoiding `fsteps` altogether and add points so to make a staircase, then fill it with `filledcurves`.

1. is there an easier way?  maybe using `boxes` would be easier?
2. supposing I go with the staircase, since I am not proficient with Gnuplot I would create the staircase outside of Gnuplot; is there an easy way of creating it inside Gnuplot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking for another variation of steps which is not covered as direct plotting style in gnuplot like in [these examples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56047577/7295599).
You have to do-it-yourself. Yes, you can do it `with boxxyerror`, check `help boxxy`.

**Script:**

```
### plot with filled fsteps
reset session

$Data <<EOD
0   1
1   4
3   3
6   7
7   5
EOD

set offset 1,1,1,0
set style fill solid 0.3 noborder
set tics out
set key noautotitle invert

plot x1=y1=NaN $Data u (x0=x1,x1=$1,y0=y1,y1=$2,(x1+x0)/2): \
        (y1/2):((x1-x0)/2):(y1/2) w boxxy lc "green" ti "filled fsteps", \
        '' u 1:2 w fsteps lw 2 lc "red" ti "fsteps"
### end script
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Addition:**

Actually, if you look carefully (zoom in), you will notice some brighter vertical lines at `x=1,3,6`.

[image]

You can avoid this if you change:

```
set style fill solid 1.0 border
```

and set the color `lc rgb 0xb3ffb3`

```
... w boxxy lc rgb 0xb3ffb3 ...
```

**Result:** (without brighter vertical lines)

[image]

**Addition 2:**

@Francesco Potortì, after your answer it looks like you are just looking for a simple bar chart with time data. You can have this simpler. Check `help strptime` and `help strcol`.

**Script:**

```
### plot a bar chart (with boxes)
reset session

$Data <<EOD
Date        Value
2024-01-10  1
2024-01-11  4
2024-01-13  3
2024-01-16  7
2024-01-17  2
2024-01-18  3
EOD

myFmt = "%Y-%m-%d"
set style fill solid
set format x "%m-%d" timedate
set boxwidth 86400 absolute    # one day 24*3600 s
set yrange[0:]

plot $Data u (strptime(myFmt,strcol("Date"))):"Value" w boxes ti "Value"
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Since I am not proficient with Gnuplot, I had to work a bit to understand it. ```x1=y1=NaN``` is an expression initialising the two variables x1 and y1: you can put a constant expression as the first argument of ```plot```. Then for each point, you compute the four arguments of the ```boxxyerror``` style. When computing the first argument, you reassign those variables using $1 and $2, which are the values taken from the first and second column of each point. Beware of parentheses, they are important.

Comment: @FrancescoPotortì glad you could "decrypt" my script. Sometimes, I do not spend too much time to explain the script in every detail, because some users will never respond. Congratulations, you did a good exercise. If your problem is solved, thank you for accepting the answer, indicating that your question is answered. PS. I have to change some little details, because if you look very carefully you will see brighter vertical lines at x=1,3 and 6.

Comment: @FrancescoPotortì one more little detail: The script above plots the boxes centered on the date. For example, if you want the box of "01-13" ranging from "01-13 00:00" to "01-13 23:59", you should add half a day, i.e.: `(strptime(myFmt,strcol("Date"))+43200)`.

Comment: Yes, once you put me on the right track I elaborated on it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

While the solution proposed by theozh is of general use and in most cases a better one, since I have exactly one point per day I came up with a solution that is in my opinion more readable. To this end, it uses the six-arg form of `boxxyerror` rather than the four-arg form used by theozh.  It is more verbose, but more readable.

So I came up with this:

```
$Data <<EOD
Date        Value
2024-01-10  1
2024-01-11  4
2024-01-13  3
2024-01-16  7
2024-01-17  2
2024-01-18  3
EOD

set xdata time
set style fill solid
set timefmt "%Y-%m-%d"
set format x "%m-%d"

plot d=24*3600 $Data \
 using 1:2:(x=timecolumn(1,"%Y-%m-%d")):(x+d):(0):"Value" with boxxyerror \
 title "Value"
```

Which produces this:
[image]

There is something that annoys me: while I can write `"Date":"Value"` as the first two arguments of `boxxyerror` (rather than `1:2`), I cannot write `timecolumn("Date","%Y-%m-%d")` rather than `timecolumn(1,"%Y-%m-%d")`.

P.S. The latest addition in theozh's answer is even simpler than mine, so I'll accept that one.

Comment: You asked for filled fsteps and didn't provide data, so I assumed something. But if I see your answer, you can do that probably much simpler `with boxes` and `set boxwidth 86400` (which is one day).